# Edit approved by no-one?

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits

Consider this approved edit (edit by me): https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/170518

Why is reviewer field blank? Who really approved the edit? This only occurs on that particular review and is the first time I've ever seen it.

Image:

> [image]

Comment: Bug probably. I don't see anyone either. It might have been you who approved it. 

Anyway, I wouldn't be too concerned about it, it got approved.

Comment: @jrg the edit was by me on someone else's post, how could I approve it myself?

Comment: well, your profile says you're a 2K user. That means you can edit without approval. At least, that's what the mobile version is telling me.

Comment: @jrg I actually have just over 1800 rep. Maybe that's my rep over the whole SE network?

Comment: Oh! Its rounding up on the mobile site. Hmm. This is weird.

Comment: This is a bug :P

Comment: @jrg *That* is most definitely a bug :P

Comment: @ThomasW. It may be, but is it a bug or a once in a lifetime glitch in the system?

Comment: @minerz029 question is can the mods and actual coders replicate it... :P